# How do I limit access of Careers profiles only to people who receive my link?

Tags: jobs, support

There's an employee viewed filter and public viewed filter.

but I don't want my page to be visible to the whole wide world.

only strictly limited to the people I send out the link to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something here, but your profile is either available via a URL and is therefore "on the Internet" and "public" or it isn't. In other words, barring some kind of password protection preventing access to it, if there is a link, then it *is* public and available to the whole wide world, assuming they know the URL.

Note: The Careers system itself doesn't provide any public (non-paid subscription) mechanisms to "discover" profiles other than through search engines that have crawled the site.

So, if what you are really looking to do is to obfuscate discovery of your profile, then I would suggest two things:

- When you make the profile public, assign a URL that nobody is likely to guess, such as a nice long GUID. [Grab one here](http://createguid.com/), they're free! :-)
- Check the public profile setting that instructs search engines not to your index your profile.

[image: Do Not Index Profile]